# Controlling the output of a method in the same class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm testing a method that calls another method within the same class.

Depending on whether this internal method call returns a result I do different things. In this case it's a `Cache` class and I'm testing my `GetOrStore` method. I want to test two paths, when `Get` returns null and when `Get` returns *something*.

What's the right approach to controlling the output of `Get` when called from `GetOrStore`? It feels like `Get` should be executed on a mocked instance however I'm unsure how to do that given two methods in the same class.

**Update**

The only thing I can think to do at this time is to make sure the cache key is removed before running the test:

```
  HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("foo"); // Make sure foo isn't in the cache.

  var output = _cache.GetOrStore("foo", () => "Foo", 100);
  Assert.AreEqual(output, "Foo");
```

This just feels wrong though. I don't actually want the HttpRuntime cache touched during my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is in Moqs `CallBase` property on mocked instances.

Setting `CallBase` to `true` ensures that any methods not explicity setup are called on the real instance of the mocked object.

This then means we can setup the `Get` method and still have `GetOrStore` executed correctly:

```
  var _mockCache = new Mock<Cache>();
  _mockCache.Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(null);
  _mockCache.CallBase = true;

  var output = _mockCache.Object.GetOrStore("foo", () => "Foo", 100);
  Assert.AreEqual("Foo", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted implies that in the cache class you are testing, the Get method calls static methods on HttpRuntime.Cache. Is this the case?

Mutable static state like this is generally best avoided. You could make a proxy class which wraps HttpRuntime.Cache and have your Cache depend on an instance of that. Then in your tests, you can substitute the proxy with a mocked version which you can easily control.

Comment: `Cache` in this case is an implimentation of `ICache` that's used to abstract away these calls to the HttpRuntime. However, somewhere down the abstraction chain I'm going to need to test the methods that end up calling the HttpRuntime. I've found a solution which I'll post as an answer.